# Julian day number to local date-time in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, julian-date

Trying to convert Julian day number to local date-time python. How to accomplish this?

```
juliandate = 2474706.5316357147
print (datetime.strptime(juliandate, '%Y%j').date())

    print (datetime.strptime(juliandate, '%Y%j').date())
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A convenient way could be using pandas' `to_datetime` with appropriate *origin* and *unit*, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

juliandate = 2459168.298
t = pd.to_datetime(juliandate, origin='julian', unit='D')
print(t)
# 2020-11-14 19:09:07.200000

# to python datetime:
# t.to_pydatetime().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Or if you like to stick to the standard lib, you could make use of `timedelta`. The epoch of julian, 12h Jan 1 4713 BC, is a bit far in the past, so it helps to introduce an offset for a more recent date, e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

dt_Offset = 2400000.500 # 1858-11-17
dt = datetime(1858, 11, 17, tzinfo=timezone.utc) + timedelta(juliandate-dt_Offset)
print(dt)
# 2020-11-14 19:09:07.199996+00:00
```

see also: [julian day on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

Note that both results are in UTC. If you want convert to a certain time zone, have a look at [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone), e.g.

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
print(dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo('US/Eastern')))
# 2020-11-14 14:09:07.199996-05:00

# or my machine's local time (CET):
print(dt.astimezone())
# 2020-11-14 20:09:07.199996+01:00
```