# Converting 7 digit dates to normal calendar dates in Databricks python

Tags: python, date, datetime, azure-databricks, julian-date

I am generating data using TPC-DS.

I load the customers table to a dataframe. The `c_first_sales_date_sk` column has values such as `2449001`, which makes me think they are Julian calendar dates of type `yyyyDD`.

So far I have tried:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, from_unixtime
df_with_date = df.withColumn("c_first_sales_date", to_date(col("c_first_sales_date_sk"), format="yyyyDDD"))
display(df_with_date)
```

Applying this, it will convert `2449001` to `2449-01-01`, which is wrong. The online convert at http://www.longpelaexpertise.com/toolsJulian.php converts the same date to `01-Jan-2024`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I convert this column properly?

Comment: see e.g. [Julian day number to local date-time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64836743/10197418) - format `yyyyDDD` is not approriate here; the number represents days since an epoch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The [tool](http://www.longpelaexpertise.com/toolsJulian.php) that you are following has specifically mentioned that the tool converts Julian date (yyddd) to calendar date.
- The 7-digit Julian date (yyyyddd) would be calculated as the number of days past (ddd) in that year (yyyy).
- If you are sure that the number is Julian date, then the code that you are using would give appropriate results. The following are some samples that I have taken to convert 7-digit Julian dates to calender dates.

```
data = [[1,'2449001'],[2,'2020111'],[3,'2010364']]
cols = ['id','jd']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=cols)
#df.show()

from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, from_unixtime,col
df_with_date = df.withColumn("ad", to_date(col("jd"), format="yyyyDDD"))
display(df_with_date)
```

[image]

- However, as indicated by @FObersteiner, the numbers might indicate something else other than the Julian date (7 digit numbers).